# How to keep update location even the object not moving using expo background service Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(),

Tags: react-native, expo

Please provide the following:
1. SDK Version: 37
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

I'm using Expo SDK version: 37, with Platform Android, I would like to ask, **is there a way to keep apps inform current user location even user not moving**, I try to record user location in **every 5 minutes**, it's working with Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync (see code below) but if the user does not move for a long time for example while user sitting, it's not updated location, **how I record user position although the user is not moving**, as code below startLocationUpdatesAsync will fire up every 10 seconds but if the object is not moving, it does not generate new location data (see const { latitude, longitude } = data.locations[0].coords)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function startWatching() {
      locationService.subscribe(onLocationUpdate)
      try {
        const { granted } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (!granted) {
          throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
        }
        let isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync('firstTask');
        if (isRegistered) {
          TaskManager.unregisterTaskAsync('firstTask')
        }
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('firstTask', {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
          timeInterval: 10000,
          activityType: Location.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
          deferredUpdatesInterval: 15000
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setErr(e);
      }
    };
    startWatching()
  }, []);

  TaskManager.defineTask('firstTask', ({ data, error }) => {
    if (error) {
      // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
      return;
    }
    if (data) {
      const { latitude, longitude } = data.locations[0].coords
      locationService.setLocation({latitude, longitude})
      // console.log('locations', locations);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why do you need the data every 5 minutes? Do you need to store or send it somewhere precisely every 5 minutes?

Comment: yes, I need to locate our sales person every 5 minutes (precisely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to record user location every 5 minutes, I can see two options:

1. Instead of listening for location changes using `Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync`, setup an interval that will retrieve current location every 5 minutes, eg.:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const location = await getCurrentLocation();
  doSomethingWithLocation(location);
}, 300000)
```

2. Continue to listen for location changes as you do, but also setup an interval that will retrieve current location from your location service every 5 minutes and use that. If location has not changed during that time, it will simply send the previous value.

Comment: Using `setInterval` in RN is not useful for when running background tasks because it will be killed when the app goes into background mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following (Where CHANGE_FETCH is when you want to update if there's a change in location and NO_CHANGE_FETCH is when there's no change in location):

```js
    // starts the background location updates
    const startLocationUpdates = async () => {
    // start the task
    console.log('gets here');
    Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(NO_CHANGE_FETCH, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      distanceInterval: 0, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
      deferredUpdatesInterval: MILI * STAG_MAXTIME, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
      // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
      foregroundService: {
        notificationTitle: 'Using your location',
        notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app and switch something off.',
      },
    });
    Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(CHANGE_FETCH, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      distanceInterval: MIN_DIST, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
      deferredUpdatesInterval: MILI * MOVING_MAXTIME, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
      // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
      foregroundService: {
        notificationTitle: 'Using your location',
        notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app and switch something off.',
       },
     });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts don't work because this task runs in the background. What worked for me was using the timestamp of each event to calculate the elapsed time

```
let lastTimestamp: number | null = null;
let accumulatedTime: number = 0;

//  Define the task to handle location updates.
TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }: ITaskResponse) => {
    if (error) {
        //  Log errors if any occur while fetching location data.
        console.error(`Error fetching location: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (data) {
        const { locations } = data;
        const { timestamp } = locations[0];

        if (lastTimestamp !== null) {
            // ⏰ Calculate the time difference between current and last timestamp.
            const timeDifference = (timestamp - lastTimestamp) / 1000;
            accumulatedTime += timeDifference;
            console.log({
                timeDifference: timeDifference.toFixed(1),
                accumulatedTime: accumulatedTime.toFixed(1),
            });

            //  Check if accumulated time has reached or exceeded 60 seconds.
            if (accumulatedTime >= 60) {
                console.log(' Reached 60 seconds! Sending data to server...');
                // Here, we'd trigger the logic to send data to the server.

                //  Adjust the accumulated time for any excess beyond 60 seconds.
                accumulatedTime -= 60;
            }
        }

        //  Update last timestamp for the next comparison.
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
    }
});
```